# SAS Create Macro variables using a macro

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro, macro-variable

I have the following dataset:

```
A1  A2  A3
B   1   0.89606
B   2   0.10058
B   3   0.00336
C   1   0.88083
C   2   0.07205
C   3   0.04712
L   1   0.93198
L   2   0.06802
L   3   0.0000
R   1   0.8096
R   2   0.18359
R   3   0.00681
```

I want to create a macro variable for each row, this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
%MACRO TEST (Input);
%DO I = 1 %TO 3;
%global mac_var_&Input._&I.;
proc sql noprint;
    select  A3
    into    :mac_var_&Input._&I.
    from    data
    where   A1= "&Input." AND A2=  &I. ;
quit;

%END;
%MEND;

%TEST(R);
%TEST(B);
%TEST(L);
%TEST(C);
```

an example of what I'd want is:

```
the macro variable &mac_var_R_1 = 0.8096
the macro variable &mac_var_C_2 = 0.07205
the macro variable &mac_var_L_3 = 0.0000
```

Comment: Why would you want to make so many macro variables?  And ones with strings representing numbers.  You will lose some resolution on the numbers by converting them into strings to store in macro variables.

Comment: This is the first stage, I need to do the same with a dataset with 180 rows next. I need to use the values stored to assign values to specific accounts. First I need to assign value A3 then the next part will depend on the accounts A3 value along with other values.

Comment: This is technically easy, but this many macro variables usually points to bad design. You can add parameters to a macro instead and drive it via a dataset.

Comment: If you want to combine the value of A3 with data in another dataset then just combine the datasets.  Do not first move the data into the text of a macro variable and then have to move it back into data again to store it with the other data.  Describe the datasets involved for answers on how to combine them.

Comment: @Tom Thanks I think this will work for the part I need to do with 180 rows but for the initial section I think I need macro variables. I was trying to use a method someone at my work told me but the call symputx makes it so much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posted code works for the data you posted.  So if you are having trouble you need show more details.  Either the actual data is not the same as your example or you are using the macro variables incorrectly.

You can generate macro variables from every observation easily using the CALL SYMPUTX() method in a data step.  You can even force them into GLOBAL macro space if the datastep is running inside a macro.

```
data _null_;
  set work.data ;
  call symputx(catx('_','mac_var',a1,a2),a3),'g');
run;
```